# Compile Java without optimization?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction

I'm working on some of the problems in Programming Pearls and I'd like to get a sense for the runtime of various programs in Java. However the optimizing compiler is making this difficult. Is there a way to run `javac` on a Mac without having the compiler make any optimizations?

Comment: Any optimizations made by javac are irrelevant, since the JRE will optimize the byte code at run-time.

Comment: The main optimisation the compiler does is expression evaluations e.g. 1 + 1 => 2  and "hi " + "there" => "hi there". It doesn't change the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Andrew Thompson is correct, the JIT is the main source of optimizations with java.

To run java without the JIT:

```
 java -Xint ...
```

Comment: Yep. In fact, javac does almost no optimization, even in obvious places. (Which of course is why it's fast.)